# Why do I get a NullPointerException when trying to disable a JFrame?

Tags: swing, nullpointerexception, jframe

I get a run-time error NullPointerException whenever I try to click the options button on my JFrame.  The JFrame is CharSelection(), and I want to disable it so that I can't click anything on that JFrame and have to click the back button to enable it again. This is the code for the button.

```
    JButton btnOptions = new JButton("Options");
    btnOptions.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            CharSelection.disabled();
            GameMenu.getMusicOption().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    btnOptions.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    btnOptions.setFocusPainted(false);
    btnOptions.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    btnOptions.setBounds(10, 669, 200, 50);
    contentPane.add(btnOptions);
```

Inside the mouseClicked event I try to disable and then retrieve the other jFrame, I know for a fact that I can retrieve the other JFrame if I take out the disabling line, the method I'm using to disable the JFrame is a method I created in the CharSelection class this is it.

```
    public static void disabled(){
    frame.setEnabled(false);
}
```

I have the frame instantiated as

```
    private static CharSelection frame;
```

This avoids any compilation errors but whenever I run the program and click this option button with this code nothing happens and I'm given the NullPointerException error.  Not sure how to fix this but you should also know that I do the exact same thing in the first Jframe GameMenu.  Except it disables the JFrame no problem, I've been trying to figure this problem out for a few days now, spending about 4 hours a day purely on this problem and can't figure it out.

The error code is this

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at game.CharSelection.disabled(CharSelection.java:1925)
at game.CharSelection$34.mouseClicked(CharSelection.java:1748)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

With the most important lines being the first three.  I can only speculate on what's causing this and without knowing the cause I have no way to fix it. Help would be appreciated thanks.

Hopefully this will help you see the code, I've taken out all the irrelevant stuff.

```
        private static CharSelection frame;


/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                frame = new CharSelection();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public CharSelection() {


    JButton btnOptions = new JButton("Options");
    btnOptions.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            CharSelection.disabled();
            GameMenu.getMusicOption().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    btnOptions.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    btnOptions.setFocusPainted(false);
    btnOptions.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    btnOptions.setBounds(10, 669, 200, 50);
    contentPane.add(btnOptions);
}

        public static void disabled(){
    frame.setEnabled(false);
}

public static void enabled(){
    frame.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: 'I have the frame instantiated as' - no, you didn't _instantiate_ it, you simply declared a static field which defaults to ... null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not instantiate the frame really. There's a

```
frame = new JFrame()
```

missing somewhere.

Plus to do this via `static` methods looks like very bad practice but it's hard to suggest a solution without seeing the whole picture.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse and it automatically instantiates the JFrame in the main method.  I have changed it so that it reads frame = new CharSelection();  Instead of CharSelection frame = new CharSelection();  As for the static I'm using that so it's possible for me to call these methods in other classes so that I may enable/disable the frame from buttons in them, I think it's possible for me not to even use methods but to tweak the code a little.  I would put the entire class code in here but it's about 2000 lines most of which has absolutely nothing to do with the program.

Comment: @user1034743 the error is a direct consequence of making the methods static :-) Simply don't.

Comment: @kleopatra I took out the methods completely and it works thank you very much, however how do I enable the frame from another class without creating new instance of CharSelection()?

Comment: Nevermind I fixed it for now.  I went to the place where I created the instance of CharSelection and changed it to public static, I'm hoping that making this static doesn't give me any problems later, it's not a method.  I accessed this from another class and used the setEnabled() method and it works.